# What is this symbol for in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I came to ask what is **!==** for at javascript I don't have any issues with it but I want to know what it does.

Comment: not strictly equal to. Here are the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Answer (score 2):

Both (===) and (!==) are called the "Strict Equality Operators". They follow the "Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm" defined by ECMA [262 5.1 Section 11.9.6](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6)

In little contrast, the equality operator (==) checks whether its two operands are equal, returning a Boolean result while attempting to convert and compare operands that are of different types.

In my opinion, its easy to understand this with examples. I hope this helps -

```
console.log(1 === 1);
// expected output: true

console.log('1' == 1);
// expected output: true

console.log('1' ===  1);
// expected output: false

console.log(0 === false);
// expected output: false

console.log(0 == false);
// expected output: true
```

Edit -

Just to answer your specific part of the question, the strict inequality operator (!==) checks the condition where the two operands being compared are not equal in either value or type.

Answer (score 0):

`===` compares two values, including the type. For example:

```
"3" === "3" //true
"3" === 3 //false
```

`!==` is a denial of that. It means that value and type isn't the same.

```
"3"!==3 //true
```